# use object name in a loop

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I'm merging some data frames that are stored in a list. For that purpose I'm using a for-loop with a `.df` command. Now, I would like to use the name of the data frame as `suffixes` in a `paste` inside my loop.

Is there a way, using the `for ( .df in [list]) {` command that I can subtract the name of the data frame currently in `.df` inside the loop?

Say I have this list with three data frames,

```
a <- list(A = data.frame(a=runif(2), b=runif(2)), 
          B = data.frame(a=runif(2), b=runif(2)), 
          C = data.frame(a=runif(2), b=runif(2)))
a

$A
          a         b
1 0.2833226 0.6242624
2 0.1741420 0.1707722

$B
           a         b
1 0.55073381 0.6082305
2 0.08678421 0.5192457

$C
           a         b
1 0.02788030 0.1392156
2 0.02171247 0.7189846
```

Now, I would like to use this loop,

```
for ( .df in a) {
 print(['command I do not know about'])
                }
```

and then have the [command I do not know about] print out A, B, C (i.e. the name of the data frame in `.df`).

Can I do that?

#### Update 2012-04-28 20:11:58 PDT

Here is a snipped of what I expect form my output using the simple loop from above,

```
for ( .df in a) {
 print(['command I do not know about'](a))
                }

[1] "A"
[1] "B"
[1] "C"
```

I could obtain this using,

```
for (x in names(a)) {
    print(x)
    }
```

but due to the nature of what I am doing I would like to use the `for ( .df in [list]) {` command in my for-loop.

Comment: use `for (nm in names(a)) { print(nm); .df = a[[nm]] }` ?

Comment: @MartinMorgan, Thank you for answering my question, but I am looking for a way to  subtract the names _inside the loop_ when the data frames are stores in the `.df` element. Sorry for not being more specific in my initial question.

Comment: what does subtract the names mean? Can you add a snippet of the expected output?

Comment: @Chase, thank you for not giving up on my question. I've added a small update with a snippet of what I would like in the output. Please let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: It seems mrdwab's answer if names(a) gives you the output you're expecting.

Comment: Basically, the answer is ... the names are gone. The loop variable is an un-named dataframe by the time it is passed into the loop. As they say in New England when the bridge is washed out .. "seek alternate routes".

Comment: @DWin, I see. I imagined that information was somehow still available. Also, thank you for the quote.

Comment: This seems like a very inefficient way to join data frames.  Maybe if you show an example of exactly what you want to obtain?  Why do you put your data frames in a list in the first place?  If it is then to merge them, why not use the do.call("rbind",...)?  If you must get the .df in your loop, try it with x in names(a) and then get(x)...

Comment: @EtienneLow-Décarie, I pull the data from a M$ Access database and the frames from the database are imported into a list, thats why things are in a list. Some vectors (variables) have similar names, that's why I want to add the name of the frame to the variables. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract both the name and the value you can't loop over the values. You can loop over either the indices or the names:

```
# Loop over indices (faster, more cumbersome)
ns <- names(a)
for(i in seq_along(a)) {
   v <- a[[i]]     # extract value
   n <- ns[[i]]    # extract name
   cat(n, ": \n")
   str(v)
}

# Loop over names (easy but slower)
for(n in names(a)) {
   v <- a[[n]]     # extract value
   cat(n, ": \n")
   str(v)
}
```

...looping over names and extracting values can be very slow for long vectors (it has n^2 time complexity).

Answer (score 0):

Not a for loop but lapply but works similar to a for loop.  Maybe this will help though I'm confused because I figured mrdwab's answer was it.

```
FUN <-function(i){
    x <- a[[i]]
    data.frame(name=rep(names(a)[[i]], nrow(x)), x)
}

LIST <- lapply(seq_along(a), FUN)

do.call("rbind", LIST)
```

Yields:

```
  name          a         b
1    A 0.90139624 0.9739355
2    A 0.34311009 0.6621689
3    B 0.07585535 0.6010289
4    B 0.37292887 0.7260832
5    C 0.17814913 0.1433650
6    C 0.24586101 0.1741114
```

Comment: did you see my update? The thing is that I would like to stick to using the `for ( .df in [list]) {` loop-structure, but 'simply' _subtract the name of the data frame inside the loop_. Does my update help explain what I am looking for in any way? If not I will make a new update will my full problem. I'm not looking for help merging anything, I'm looking for help getting at the name of the element sores in `.df` during/inside the loop.

Comment: I do that here by passing the index to the lapply (or in your case the loop)