# exclusively mark y's variables when merging in loop

Tags: r, for-loop, merge, customization

As a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369187/use-object-name-in-a-loop) I am now looking for a way to mark only non-unique variables from the y-data-frame when I merge.

The default for `suffixes` is to look for a vector that has the length of two.

Say I have this list,

```
a <- list(A = data.frame(id = c(01, 02), a=runif(2), b=runif(2)), 
          B = data.frame(id = c(01, 02), b=runif(2), c=runif(2)),
          C = data.frame(id = c(01, 02), c=runif(2), d=runif(2)))
a
$A
  id         a         b
1  1 0.6922513 0.9966336
2  2 0.9216164 0.8256744

$B
  id         b         c
1  1 0.2242940 0.7058331
2  2 0.4474754 0.9228213

$C
  id        c         d
1  1 0.969796 0.1761250
2  2 0.633697 0.6618188
```

then I make some *customization* where I merge some of the data frames together one by oen, here exemplified by taking out one data frame,

```
df <- a[[1]]
a <- a[setdiff(names(a), names(a[1]))]
```

then I merge the list in this way,

```
for(i in seq_along(a)) {
   v <- a[[i]]     # extract value
   ns <- names(a)
   n <- ns[[i]]    # extract name
   df <-merge(df, v, by.x="id", by.y="id", all.x=T, 
              suffixes=paste(".", n, sep = ""))
}
df
  id         a       b.B       bNA       c.C      cNA         d
1  1 0.6922513 0.9966336 0.2242940 0.7058331 0.969796 0.1761250
2  2 0.9216164 0.8256744 0.4474754 0.9228213 0.633697 0.6618188
```

The issue is, as shown above, that R adds a mark to both non-unique variables, but as I only supplied one name `n` I get an `NA` on the 'other' variable.' In the example above I get an .B-suffix on the variable from the A-data-frame.

Is there a way I can either add the correct data frame name to both variables or (preferred) exclusively mark y's variables when merging?

Comment: The above example can be solved with `do.call("cbind", a)`. :P

Comment: It's not so hard to imagine the OP's real data frames having id's that are not all identical, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry... It took me a little while to understand your problem. But, you're... like... 99% there.

Change the argument:

```
suffixes = paste(".", n, sep = "")
```

to:

```
suffixes = c("", paste(".", n, sep = ""))
```

And you should be OK. By doing this, I got a `df` that looks like this:

```
> df
  id          a           b        b.B         c        c.C           d
1  1 -0.6039805  0.08297807 0.06426459  2.787147 -0.9566280 -0.36054991
2  2 -0.1694382 -0.95296450 0.37144139 -1.346691  0.7072892  0.09239593
```

By the way, instead of all of this, did you try some of the other recommendations from earlier Stackoverflow posts? Somewhere I remember seeing something using `Reduce` which got me to this partial solution (with your original "a" data):

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="id", all=TRUE, suffixes=c("", "_2")), 
       a, accumulate=FALSE)
```

which gives you output like:

```
  id          a           b        b_2         c        c_2           d
1  1 -0.6039805  0.08297807 0.06426459  2.787147 -0.9566280 -0.36054991
2  2 -0.1694382 -0.95296450 0.37144139 -1.346691  0.7072892  0.09239593
```

Are either of these more useful or closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question, your `suffixes = c("", paste(".", n, sep = ""))` solved my problem in the way I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @EricD.Brean, the answer was actually already in your post! It wasn't until I re-read it and read your line *The default for suffixes is to look for a vector that has the length of two* and I looked at your code again that I had sort of a "wha... but he only has one..." moment...

Comment: Unfortunately I din't have that moment. Again, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This was a fun little puzzle. I cheated and "borrowed" heavily from Hadley's `merge_recurse` function in the **reshape** package:

```
merge_recurse1 <- function (dfs, ...) 
{
    n <- length(dfs)
    if (!is.null(names(dfs))){

    }
    if (length(dfs) == 2) {
        merge(dfs[[1]], dfs[[2]],all = TRUE,sort = FALSE,
            suffixes = c('',names(dfs)[2]), ...)
    }
    else {
        merge(Recall(dfs[-n],...), dfs[[n]],all = TRUE,sort = FALSE,
            suffixes = c('',names(dfs)[n]),...)
    }
}

> merge_recurse1(a,by = "id")
  id         a         b        bB         c        cC         d
1  1 0.2536158 0.6083147 0.3060572 0.1428531 0.6403072 0.4621454
2  2 0.9839910 0.7256161 0.2203161 0.6653415 0.1496376 0.8767888
```

In addition to the suffix changes I made, I found I need to add a `...` argument to `Recall` just to get `merge_recurse` to work the way I thought it should. Not sure if that's a bug or if I'm just misunderstanding the function.